# How far away must galaxies be before current telescopes can no longer measure how quickly they are rotating around one another or internally?

Tags: observational-astronomy, redshift

What is the distance limit and does it depend on the size of the galaxy and on noise and interference from gas clouds and our own Milky Way?

Comment: Here's a report on finding rotation curves of galaxies at z=2~3  https://www.eso.org/sci/publications/messenger/archive/no.125-sep06/messenger-no125-11-14.pdf It describes itself as "First convincing evidence for rotating
discs at z ~ 2" and it also describes rotation in a gravitationally lensed galaxy at z=3.2 and finally notes that the ELT and JWST could make such observations routine.

Comment: The galaxies in that paper look really asymmetrical .Presumably they became more symmetrical with time.

Comment: Thats an unintuitive conclusion. We'd expect to see more symetry rather than less symetry over distance. Plus on first principles I'd expect it to work the other way around with time smoothing out asymetry.